# What is the best way to move a large and complex site (which will need extensive testing) to a new server?

Tags: dns, migration

We need to move a large and complex site to a new server, and we need to ensure there is minimal downtime / disruption for our members.

This is what we have in mind:

1. Create a new domain (e.g. oursite.club) on the new server, for testing purposes. (We're planning on doing this because the temporary URL that works with some hosts / sites does not appear to work on ours)
2. Upload all existing code and import all databases to the new server.
3. Make any changes to allow for the new server path / domain name / different database names, where necessary.
4. Thoroughly test the .club site.
5. Add the current live domain (e.g. oursite.com) to the new server as an alias of the .club domain.
6. Once we're confident the new site works, change the DNS of the .com to point to the new server.
7. Also, add htaccess redirects on the old .com site to point to the same page on the .club domain, so that the site can still be accessed by those members for whom nameservers are not yet propagated.

After everything is working and all nameservers should have propagated, we want to make the .com the "real" domain and optionally retain the .club as an alias (i.e. swap the two domains on the new server).

This is what we have in mind:

8. Delete the add-on domain from the new server (i.e. the .club) and the alias domain (i.e. the .com) - but leave all the code / data where it is.
9. Re-add the .com, but point that at the server path where the .club code was uploaded.
10. Re-add the .club, but as an alias of the .com (or use URL forwarding at our domain registrar).
11. Make sure everything still works.
12. Update the htaccess redirects on the old server to send .com traffic to the .com domain on the new server, just in case there are any nameservers still pointing to the old server.

Since the nameservers for the two domains are already pointing to the new server, and that won't change, we thought this would offer the fastest way of swapping these two domains around.

We've done some testing with spare domains and a default WP blog, and this seems to work, but we wanted to call on your collective experience here to ask:

A. Will this work?

B. If not, what have we forgotten to take into account?

C. If so, good, but is there a better / easier way to accomplish this (especially the bit where we flip-flop the two domain names on the new server so that the current .com domain remains as the primary one to use)? For example, would it work if we add the .com to the new server (instead of creating a .club) and then edit our local hosts file during testing? Or can we use a VirtualHost directive to help with the domain swapping?

Although we've been building / running site for many years now, this is the first time we've had to move a membership site that is business-critical and where any excessive downtime / issues will cause us and/or our members real issues.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something significant here (I don't entirely understand your need to flip flop the domains at the end), so I'll quite likely change this answer depending on comments etc (or delete it if I've completely missed a point!)

My approach to this would be

1. Set your DNS TTL for www.example.com to a very low number, 600 seconds perhaps. Don't plan the move until your current TTL expires (from the moment you make the change)
2. Create website on new server,configure the site under your example.club domain *and* example.com
3. Configure the hosts file on your testing machines with the IP Address of the server, and www.example.com This way your testing machines are going to actually test the full structure of example.com.
4. Test against example.club if you are concerned about broken links to the new domain, but since that is only temporary, it shouldn't really matter.
5. when it is tested and you are confident it is working, switch the DNS over.
6. Once you are comfortable that everything is working as expected reset your DNS TTL to a more sane figure.

As long as your database is in sync, there would be minimal (if any) downtime from this and at the end you can simply delete the example.club reference without any impact.

Depending on the value of the site, and the impact of potential downtime it might be worth putting a load balancer between both sites, and gradually increase the traffic that is sent to the new site so you can monitor progress. (you could use a load balancer from Azure which has no restrictions on being used against external sites)

Comment: Michael,

Thanks for taking the time to reply. You've understood what we needed pretty well, and your proposed sequence of actions seems doable, for the most part.

For example, our current web host won't allow us to change the TTL (nor will they do it for us, as we're currently on a shared hosting plan), which is a shame.

We hadn't actually planned on having two instances of the site once we're done (the second domain was only intended to be a temporary measure while we test), but if we do, then the idea of a load balancer is a good one, so thanks for the reference.